# How to control a redstone lamp with command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have to control lamps with a sun light detector. However, the location of the lamps is very special so I have difficulty to place the redstone line. I wonder if there is a way to control the lamps with a command block remotely?

I need to keep them on during the daytime and turn them off at night.

Comment: @dly Actually I don't see the connection between the command you posted and my question......

Comment: @dly This question is primarily how to turn on/off the lamp remotely, which your link doesn't seem to answer at all.

Comment: Would it be fine to have one block adjacent of the lamp, or does it need to be completely on its own?

Comment: I'm not sure if they removed this, but try /setblock and change the lamps into powered_lamps

Comment: @colorfusion It's not a lamp, it's several lamps which are placed specially so I'm unable to place power source or redstone line to enlighten them( setting a block adjacent of the lamp seems to be impossible too) together with the same control structure. So it has to be remotely.

Comment: Don't think it's possible if you've got multiple lamps next to eachother and can't setblock next to them, then.

Answer (score 1):

My easy solution:

Enter this to the right command block:

[image: Minecraft screenshot]

The X Y Z should correspond to a block adjacent to the redstone lamp.

You get the inverted daylight sensor by right-clicking on a regular one.

Here are the commands for pasting:

Right command block: `/setblock x y z minecraft:air 0`

Left command block: `/setblock x y z redstone_block`

Comment: lol I made one 8 step tutorial before I realized that I can do it like this it took me 3 hours and this tooke me 5 minutes lol

Comment: as compact as it can get I think

Answer (score 1):

Use two command blocks, one connected to a daylight sensor and one to an inverted daylight sensor. Set them both to repeat.

Inverted:

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:redstone_lamp
```

Regular:

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp
```

x, y, and z are the coordinates of the lamp. No blocks around the lamp are required.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Minecraft, you need to use this command

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:redstone_lamp[lit=true]
```