# Activate lever with command block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to use a `command block` to activate a `lever` in Bedrock edition. I thought I could use `/setblock` but the syntax for Bedrock edition doesn't seem to support it:

```
/setblock <position> <tileName> [tileData] [replace¦destroy¦keep]
```

I ran into [a similar issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387002/activate-redstone-lamp-with-command-block) with trying to set the state of a `redstone lamp` recently and discovered that we've been provided with a `lit redstone lamp` object to use instead. However, no such variant exists for the lever:

[image: Object list for lever in the command suggestions.]

How can I activate a lever with a command block in Bedrock edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per on the wiki,

[image]

You'll want to:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ lever ["open_bit":1,"lever_direction":"north"] replace
```

(Don't actually `/setblock ~ ~ ~` unless you want to replace your command block)

`/setblock` is supported on Bedrock, but some block have rejigged states and syntax and some commands changed.

Also, you'll need to know which direction your lever is facing.

Comment: Thankfully my design was able to be completed with a `redstone comparator` instead, but I left my question up to help future readers. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

While I type this, Bedrock Edition is still utilizing the data value.

Using the official Wiki, just add `8` to the data value to make an unpowered one powered, and just subtract `8` to make it unpowered (for `/setblock` and the like).

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever#Metadata)

Answer (score 0):

In Bedrock inactive levers have id's 0-8 whereas active levers have id's 9-15

```
/fill 0 0 0 10 10 10 lever 11 replace lever
```